# Custom class no work in input type checkbox after pagination DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Well, I have a table, por example:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Estatus</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>
            <tr>Title1</tr>
            <tr>Data1</tr>
            <tr><button class="btn btn-danger eliminar"  id="785">Eliminar</button></tr>
        <tr><input type="checkbox"  name="activoinactivo" id="123"></tr>
        </td>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add a personalized style to each entry and I do it this way

```
 var table = $('#datatable-example').DataTable();
    table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('input-switch');
   });
```

the problem is that it does not work on the next page

[image]

[image]

What do I need to make it work properly?

Plugin URL: https://datatables.net/manual/

Comment: please add any custom css

Comment: It does not work either What I have to see because manually does not work.

Comment: I try it: 
<input type="checkbox" data-on-color="primary" name="activoinactivo" id="'.$id.'" class="input-switch activoinactivo"  data-size="medium" data-on-text="ON" data-off-text="Off" > but, not work.

Comment: what is in class input-switch?

Comment: your table has no id called datatable_example, it is #mytable

Comment: they have the same identifier, it was an error when copying and pasting

Comment: i think ,you have to reinitialize switch plugin everytime you click the page number

Comment: And how is that done? I do not understand :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input[type="checkbox"]').each()` will only target inputs that is visible (or exists) in the DOM. Look at [**`createdCell`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) and [**`columnDefs`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs). You do not provide your DT initialization, but basically you should go with :

```js
columnDefs: [{
  targets: 3,
  createdCell: function(cell, cellData, rowData) {
    $(cell).find('input').addClass('input-switch')
  }
}]
```

By that you ensure you target all inputs, also those DT removes and injects to the DOM when you switch page. Besides that you have malformed markup

```html
<td>
  <tr>Title1</tr>
  <tr>Data1</tr>
  <tr><button class="btn btn-danger eliminar"  id="785">Eliminar</button></tr>
  <tr><input type="checkbox"  name="activoinactivo" id="123"></tr>
</td>
```

should be

```html
<tr>
  <td>Title1</td>
  <td>Data1</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger eliminar"  id="785">Eliminar</button></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"  name="activoinactivo" id="123"></td>
</tr>
```